# How to run, monitor and stop a PHP script using SSH on a shared webserver?

Tags: php, ssh, monitoring

Can a normal member (not an admin) of a shared webserver with (limited) SSH access run, monitor and stop a PHP script through SSH? If so, how would all three actions be done by the user?

---

I tried to use the command "top", but it only listed actual top level processes, not PHP scripts. I have also managed to start a PHP script using the commands provided in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612115/how-do-i-run-a-php-script-through-ssh). But what about termination and monitoring of the currently running PHP scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK you can not as the script runs under different user than the one you can log into via SSH.

Comment: Is it not possible to run the script under the same user as the SSH session?

Answer (score 4):

If you are running the php script from the console like so:

```
php myscript.php
```

Then you should be able to kill the process:

```
killall php
```

You should probably use `top` to find the pid and then use `kill` in place of `killall`

Comment: Quote: "I tried to use the command "top", but it only listed actual top level processes, not PHP scripts." No PHP processes are listed there, as far as I've seen. Should I try something like "top php" ?

Comment: If php is not in the top then it is not running or it is lower in the list then you can see. As top only shows the first few processes. If your system has it you can use `pidof php`.

Comment: Not all systems have it sadly. Try `ps -A | grep php`.

Answer (score 1):

Re: ps not showing php processes

Keep in mind that a lot of hosts have a grid running and php processes are running on a different machine altogether. Depending on the configurations, these processes may never be visible to you via shell. You may have better luck with php scripts :)

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I used to run this:

```
watch ps u -u your_user_name
```

and It was working, I could see how many php script were running and time, memory and cpu consumption. That was very helpful because I was doing some datamining and text analyzing ... anyway, I did some server upgrade and for some how It stop working, nothing is showing.